# jQuery.post not POSTing

Tags: php, jquery, email

I am trying to use jQuery to post data to an emailus.php script.

Here is the script part:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#submitt').click(function(){
        jQuery.post("/emailus.php", jQuery("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {

            jQuery('#success').html(response);

        });
        return false;

    });

});
</script>
```

and here is the HTML used:

```
<form action="" method="get" id="mycontactform" >
<label for="name">Your Name:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="name"  class="cleann" /><br />
<label for="email">Your Email:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="email"  class="cleann" /><br />
<label for="message">Your Message:</label><br />
<textarea name="message" class="cleann" rows="7"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" value="send" id="submitt" class="cleannsubmit" /><div id="success" style="color:green;"></div>
</form>
```

and here is the php script:

```
<?php

// Here we get all the information from the fields sent over by the form.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'nohanada@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Fortrove Contact';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message.'\n\nItem:'.$itemname;

print_r($_POST);
if($name && $email && $message){
    if (eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
        mail($to, $subject, $message); 
        echo "Your email was sent!"; 
    }
    else echo "<span style='color:red'>Invalid email format.</span>";
}
else echo "<span style='color:red'>Please fill all fields</span>";
?>
```

Problem is that it does not POST the actual fields to the php script. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: if you have ajax request why are you submitting the form

Comment: I only added that to try and see if it works, but it doesn't. Let me remove that from the questions.

Comment: When you say `does not POST the actual fields to the php script`, what do you by this ? is the values null at the php script side ?

Comment: Open the debug console on your browser and tell if you see the ajax query or any js error please

Comment: Yes, I print_r($_POST) and it's empty.

Comment: There are no errors by the script. I actually get the reply from the emailus.php just fine (the "Please fill all fields" error).

Comment: You need to pass the data to be transmitted to target script in a name value pair like this inside .post() ,`$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`

Comment: But isn't that the whole purpose of .serialize()? The values come from the input fields, they are not static.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t923M/1/

Comment: It's not working for me. you can check it live here: http://www.fortrove.com/index.php/louis-vuitton-18k-yellow-gold-pearl-heart-chain-layered-bracelet.html when you click on "Email Fortrove", it will popup the form for you.

Comment: looks like you have a form inside another one??

Comment: you have placed the `mycontactform` inside `product_addtocart_form` that is the reason

Comment: Oh! Wow, I missed that. PErfect. Thank you Arun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have placed the `mycontactform` inside `product_addtocart_form` that is the reason which is not allowed so the browser seems to be remocing the `mycontactform`